# Почему так отображается текст?

Tags: php, html, вёрстка

Здравствуй, ХешКод! Вот решил сделать меню на `html`, и тут возникла проблема, я не знаю, как её решить. Помогите, пожалуйста. Зайдите [сюда](http://automatic-surfing.org.ua/test/) и посмотрите, я там сделал так отдельный файл `left.php`, где лежит само меню, и я его просто в `index.php` инклудил, и, когда начала писать текст ниже, он стал писаться под меню, а мне надо чтобы он был напротив меню. Вот код `index.php`:

```
<head>
<title>Автоматический сёрфинг</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<? include("header.php"); ?>
<center>
<h1 class="title">Это мой сайт</h1>
<pre>
Здорова молодые.
</pre>
</center>
<? include("footer.php"); ?>
</body>
```

Comment: оё буксы и сюда добрались...

Comment: Причём тут букс?

Answer (score 1):

[Вот ссылка.](http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/tipovye-makety/rezinovyi-dvukhkolonochnyi-maket)

Почитайте как сделать макет.

По простому это так:
оберните середину (от инклауд до инклауд) в

```
<div style="float:right;">`тут середина`</div>
```

Comment: Попробовал ваш код, работает но не правильно, зайдите на сайт что указан в первом посте.

Comment: <div style="clear:both;">footer</div> и футер будет внизу. Но всё же зайдите на сайт что я указал выше и попробуйте выполнить. И как уже было замечено, почему у Вас <head> и <body> повторяется столько раз, допускается только 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="overflow: hidden">
 <div style="float: left">Левая часть</div>
 <div style="float: right">Правая часть</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Оооо всё теперь работает как надо, но вопрос как footer.php теперь опустить? 0_О А то текст поднялся и футер вместе с ними, просто у меня в шапке инклудится левая часть(может как-то правильнее сделать?), и может быть из-за этого?

Comment: Мне вот интересно одно.. Кто Вас так верстать учил? Почему повторяются везде <head> и <body>, раза 4 уже...

Когда юзаешь float, необходимо добавлять overflow: hidden, в большинстве случаев там его нет, поэтому и так получается.

Comment: Меня верстке учил youtube... Хорошо понятно, щяс попробую исправить.

Comment: Значит youtube плохо учит. Читайте лучше книги.